# Unable to run web api (gateway) project - This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address:

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to setup and run this git project - https://github.com/johnph/simple-transaction#WebApi-Endpoints

I have successfully clean up and re-build the whole solution. I have successfully configure to perform EF Core Code-First migration and database was successfully created with 2 tables in it:

- AccountTransaction
- AccountSummary

I could run Transaction.WebApi which opens up http://localhost:60243/swagger/index.html. But, I could not run the other 2 web api projects: Gateway.WebApi or Identity.WebApi. The error occured is `This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address:`

I could start SimpleBanking.ConsoleApp project. Test data is \src\Services\Identity\Services\UserService.cs. But it returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. App interrupted. App closed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run this project successfully.

Make sure you run 3 servers Gateway.WebApi, Identity and Transaction.

Only then you can run Console app.

In the Console even if you put the incorrect username or password the system still telling you it Login successfully, which misleading. Then when you choose one of the options you get:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
App interrupted.
App closed.*

Make sure to monitor the log for errors

Comment: I managed to run the `transaction` api but when I run gateway api, the browser will open up as http://localhost:54784/api/values but the error mentioned in my original post. I have already set the connection string in my gateway api. How do I monitor the log ?

Comment: i also tried http://localhost:54203/api/user/authenticate but it says `This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405`

Comment: You first call to a WebApi has to be a Post request with the correct username and password. If everything is good it will return a jwt token. Any subsequent call to withdraw, balance, etc will need to pass this token.

That is why you cannot just open the browser an expect to work. Use the console app for that

Comment: I use the command line to run these services. I can see the output logs there